# How to make a button group in to a block in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and I have 2 selectors that I want to make a block so that it takes the complete width, but adding `btn-block` didn't seem to do much in this case.

Is it possible to do this with native Bootstrap?

```
  <div class="form-group btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" required=""><i class="fa fa-female"></i> Female
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" required=""><i class="fa fa-male"></i> Male
    </label>
  </div>
```

Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/ifKuYsbCZI

Answer (score 1):

You can use `btn-group-justified`

```
 <div class="form-group btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
          <label class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
             <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" required=""><i class="fa fa-female"></i> Female
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
             <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" required=""><i class="fa fa-male"></i> Male
          </label>
 </div>
```

http://bootply.com/Y3toXvLUCW

Answer (score 0):

I think the bootstrap class you are looking for is `.btn-group-justified`

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups-justified